# android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I'm getting

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
>
> caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated

after adding a new fingerprint and then try to login into my application.

This happens only on Android 7.1 and above.

NOTE: I already added code for

> KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException

to recreate cipher.

Please let me know if you found any solution for this issue.

Comment: You haven't provided an exact step-by-step, but I've seen an issue issue that could occur after adding a new fingerprint directly after a lockout on the Nexus 5X running Android 7.1: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137351